# Read/Write into a database for a particular rate

Tags: database, multithreading

I'm writing a multithreaded program to check the performance of a database server. In my program, one thread should access(read/wright) the database for a given rate(eg. 100 times per second) But my problem is, how can I access the database for the given rate. How can I send 1000 requests in one second to the database.